# Pandas Data frame Finding data related to rolling one year

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have 2 data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'date':['2015-12-01','2016-02-02','2017-05-01']})

df1

        date    id
0   2015-12-01  1
1   2016-02-02  2
2   2017-05-01  3
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'book_date':['2014-08-03','2016-01-12','2017-08-01','2015-02-01','2015-05-01','2016-09-01']})
df2


    book_date   id
0   2014-08-03  1
1   2016-01-12  2
2   2017-08-01  3
3   2015-02-01  1
4   2015-05-01  2
5   2016-09-01  3
```

I want to join both data frames and for each ID in df1 i would like to get all book_date from df2 where book_date in df2 is in the range of past one year to date in df1.

so for id 1 i want only `2015-02-01` but not `2014-08-03`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can `merge` then apply your condition with the result

```
df1.merge(df2).loc[lambda x : (x.date-x.book_date).dt.days<=365]
Out[503]: 
        date  id  book_date
1 2015-12-01   1 2015-02-01
2 2016-02-02   2 2016-01-12
3 2016-02-02   2 2015-05-01
4 2017-05-01   3 2017-08-01
5 2017-05-01   3 2016-09-01
```

Comment: @S_Ymln yw ~ :-) happy coding